# How to change the value of this input code with javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, google-custom-search

This is the javascript -

```
  <script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en', style: google.loader.themes.BUBBLEGUM});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var customSearchOptions = {};
  var orderByOptions = {};
  orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
  customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
  customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
  var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('001216773833632189276:ki_enp2eefa', customSearchOptions);
  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
  var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
  options.setAutoComplete(true);
  customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
  }, true);
  </script>
```

And its returning input code is with table column-
      `<td class="gsc-search-button">`
      `<input type="button" value="Search" class="gsc-search-button" title="search">`
      `</td>`

Here i want to set the value `GO`. How can i get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only have 1 element in your page follow this:

```
var searchField = document.getElementsByClassName("gsc-search-button")[0];
searchField.value = "GO";
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/uN2NV/

for multiple elements Try this:

```
var searchField = document.getElementsByClassName("gsc-search-button");
for(var i =0; i<searchField.length;i++)
{
    searchField[i].value = "GO";
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uN2NV/1/

For distinct element among multiple elements that share the same class:

```
var searchField = document.getElementById("distinct");
searchField.value = "GO";
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uN2NV/2/

Comment: That will only work if its the first element on the page with that class

Comment: better.  I upvoted.  Still won't work if there are multiple elements and op only wants to get this one.  If they really just want this element, the only safe way to do it without more context is by adding an ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector(".gsc-search-button").value = "GO";
```

Comment: That will only work if its the first element on the page with that class.

Comment: @ben336: Can you tell from the question if that'll be an issue in this case?

Comment: no, you can't tell, which is why its a good idea to specify that as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just that element, give it an ID

then search for it

```
var btn = document.getElementById("searchButton");

btn.value = "GO";
```

If you know that this will be the only item on the page with this class, or want to select all elements with the gsc-search-button class, then one of the other answers will work without modifying the markup.